$\frac{x^2}{x+1} + \frac{(1-x)^2}{2-x} \geq \frac{1}{3}$ for $x\in(0,1)$ using AM-GM?
Given a real value $x$ such that $0 \leq x \leq 1$, show that
$$\frac{x^2}{x+1} + \frac{(1-x)^2}{2-x} \geq \frac{1}{3}.$$
The proof using Cauchy is rather simple, but I'm not sure how to do this with AM-GM. I've tried multiplying both sides with 3 or with $(x+1)$$(2-x)$, and some other approaches by decomposing the fractions. I think maybe I can use the fact that for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $(x+1)$ is symmetric with $(2-x)$. I saw this problem on Brilliant.org btw.

One idea might be to let $y=1-x$. Then the bound is more symmetrical: $\frac{x^2}{x+1}+\frac{y^2}{y+1} \geq \frac13$ when $x+y=1$ and $x,y\geq 0$.

Presumably you got it from this wiki page. If so, think about which category it fits in - The only natural one is "application on terms obtained after rearranging creatively".  Tri's solution was what I had in mind.

Using AM-GM inequality, we get the followings:
$$\dfrac{x^2}{x+1}+\frac{x+1}{9} \ge 2\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{x+1}\cdot\frac{x+1}{9} }=\dfrac{2x}{3} \quad (1)$$
and
$$\dfrac{(1-x)^2}{2-x}+\frac{2-x}{9} \ge 2\sqrt{\dfrac{(1-x)^2}{2-x}\cdot\frac{2-x}{9} }=\dfrac{2(1-x)}{3} \quad (2)$$
Adding two inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields the desired inequality.

I think this is the intended solution. Nice!

I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use Cauchy-Schwarz in this situation, but a solution using AM-GM could go as follows. First, rewrite the expression as
$$\frac{x^2}{x+1}+\frac{(1-x)^2}{2-x}=\left(x-1+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)+\left(-x+\frac{1}{2-x}\right)=\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2-x}-1.$$
By AM-GM, $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2-x}\geq\frac{2}{\sqrt{(x+1)(2-x)}}$. By AM-GM we also have $3\geq 2\sqrt{(x+1)(2-x)}$. Combining, we have $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2-x}\geq\frac{4}{3}$, meaning the original expression is $\geq\frac 13$.

That's neat. The problem is listed under an AM-GM article, so I figure a solution using AM-GM would be interesting.

A related approach is to rearrange the desired inequality as $\frac{2}{(x+1)^{-1}+(2-x)^{-1}} \leq \frac32$, in which case this follows from AM-HM inequality instead. (The proof strategy used here may indeed amount to a proof of AM-HM from two uses of AM-GM.)

$$\frac{x^2}{x+1} + \frac{1-2x+x^2}{2-x} \geq \frac{1}{3}.$$
$$\frac{x^2}{x+1} + \frac{1}{2-x} -x \geq \frac{1}{3}.$$
$$\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{2-x} \geq \frac{4}{3}.$$
$$\frac{3}{(x+1)(2-x)}  \geq \frac{1}{3}.$$
$$9  \geq (x+1)(2-x).$$
Since by AM-GM: $$3={(x+1) +(2-x)}\geq 2\sqrt{(x+1)(2-x)}$$ we are done.
